# Changing the key from a map while iterating it using streams

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have the next code:

```
 result.forEach((county, cityMap) -> result.put(county, cityMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
         // .map(entry -> {(StringUtils.capitalize(entry.getKey()), Map.Entry<String, City>::getValue}) -i tried this but it doesn't work
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey((o1, o2) -> {

                AlphaNumericComparator comparator = new AlphaNumericComparator();

                return comparator.compare(o1, o2);
            }))

            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new))));
```

cityMap.entrySet() is a map with key of type String and value of type City, which is a class defined by me.

Before sorting, i want to capitalize every key from cityMap.entrySet(). How can I make that?

I mention that I made that before and it worked but now I want to make the capitalization of keys before sorting them

```
result.forEach((county,cityMap) -> result.put(county,cityMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey((o1, o2) -> {

                AlphaNumericComparator comparator = new AlphaNumericComparator();

                return comparator.compare(o1, o2);
            }))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> StringUtils.capitalize(entry.getKey()), Map.Entry<String, City>::getValue,
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap<String, City>::new))));
```

Comment: Why do you need to use streams here. In fact, streams is not a good candidate to solve your problem. Just use an iterator with a for loop and do it.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala i already used streams and it woked, but now I want to make the capitalization of keys before sorting them

Comment: It's a very strange and inefficient behavior to instantiate a comparator for every comparison. Assuming that `AlphaNumericComparator` does implement `Comparator` appropriately (as its class name suggests), replace `Map.Entry.comparingByKey((o1, o2) -> {

                AlphaNumericComparator comparator = new AlphaNumericComparator();

                return comparator.compare(o1, o2);
            })` with the much simpler expression `Map.Entry.comparingByKey(new AlphaNumericComparator())`.

Comment: Besides that, the mapping step must return an object, e.g. `.map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry(StringUtils.capitalize(e.getKey()), e.getValue()))`. If you are using Java 9 or newer and neither key nor value are ever `null` you can use `.map(e -> Map.entry(StringUtils.capitalize(e.getKey()), e.getValue()))` instead.

Comment: And for the overall operation, instead of `result.forEach((county, cityMap) -> result.put(county, ...));` you can use `result.replaceAll((county, cityMap) -> ...);` which avoids doing an unnecessary map lookup for every entry.